# Collect Code Coverage Causes Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, code-coverage, mstest

When running the `dotnet test --collect "Code Coverage"` for my .Net Core 2.1 application, I'm presented immediately with "Out of Memory" exceptions.  Removing `--collect "Code Coverage"` allows the tests to successfully run.  What can I do to fix this issue?  I've read other SO articles about switching to `Release|x86`, and other target platform tweaks, but none of them have worked.

Comment: Are you perhaps running `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe` rather than `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` ?

Comment: I've tried running the tests with the full path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` and it resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

we had same problem. using **any cpu** and configuration **debug** is solved our problem.
We also used "command line" task, instead of "dotnet" in the pipeline.